# Inserting specific items from arrays into database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to split up an input by the user and insert only the second element and then every element after that. Don't worry about any of the database code, it all works fine.

Basically the user is going to input !add name output
If it sees !add, its going to log the name and output to the database. The name is one word but the output can be a string of many words. The problem is when I split the string the output becomes too much to manage and I don't know how to insert it into the database.

This is what I have so far

```
public void onMessage(message) {

    String[] splitMessage = message.split(" ");

    if (splitMessage[0] == "!add") {
        try {
            conn = connectionMain.getConnection();
            String query = "insert ignore into commands(name, output) values(?,?)";

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, splitMessage[1]);
            pstmt.setString(2, /*Question*/);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            /* Catch/Finally Statements Below */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but you may want to use `message.split(" ",3)` instead of `message.split(" ")` and then use `splitMessage[2]` to set your second parameter. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int- but take care that the resulting array is only guaranteed to have _at most_ 3 elements (ie: it could have less)

Comment: Oh I missed that on the docs. I need to improve my skim reading skills. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to substring after the first (space) separator.

```
int idx = message.indexOf(" ");
String question = message.substring(idx + 1);

pstmt.setString(2, question);
```